# What are _Base properties in Powershell and how do I use them?

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

Take for instance the output of

```
gwmi Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk
```

Among properties we find

```
PercentDiskTime
```

and

```
PercentDiskTime_Base
```

The documentation about this class  at learn.microsoft.com makes no sense to me as it only states that the latter is "Base value for PercentDiskTime"

They're both very large numbers and I don't understand how to link one to the other.

My actual problem is that I need to log the disk activity and the formatted output may exceed 100% therefore one has to compute the value manually using raw values. I found old discussions online about this problem but the solution point to dead links.  I also found code but it doesn't work properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PercentDiskTime_Base` property represents the private timer for the `PercentDiskTime` used in calculations ***FormattedData***_PerfDisk from ***RawData***_PerfDisk:

> **[PERF_PRECISION_100NS_TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms804015(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)**
>
> **Description**:  This counter type shows a value that consists of two counter values: the count of the elapsed time of the event being
>   monitored, and the "clock" time from a private timer in the same
>   units. It measures time in 100 ns units.
>
> This counter type differs from other counter timers in that the clock
>   tick value accompanies the counter value eliminating any possible
>   difference due to latency from the function call. Precision counter
>   types are used when standard system timers are not precise enough for
>   accurate readings.
>
> **Generic type**: Percentage
>
> **Formula**:  `NX – N0 / D1 – D0` where the numerator (`N`) represents the counter value and the denominator (`D`) *is the value of the
>   private timer*. The private timer has the same frequency as the 100 ns
>   timer.
>
> **Average**:  `NX – N0 / D1 – D0`
>
> **Example**:  `PhysicalDisk\% Disk Time`

For details and explanation, let's start analyzing ***[Qualifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmisdk/property-qualifiers-for-performance-counter-classes?redirectedfrom=MSDN#property-qualifiers-for-raw-and-formatted-performance-classes)*** of the following properties (sorry, *Microsoft is no longer updating linked content regularly*):

### From [`Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa394308(v%3Dvs.85)):

> **PercentDiskTime**: Data type: `uint64`, Access type: Read-only
>
> *Qualifiers*: [CounterType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmisdk/countertype-qualifier) (542573824) , DefaultScale (0) , [PerfDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmisdk/perfdetail-qualifier) (100)
>
> Percentage of elapsed time that the selected disk drive is busy
>   servicing read or write requests.
>
> **PercentDiskTime_Base**: Data type: `uint64`, Access type: Read-only
>
> *Qualifiers*: [CounterType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmisdk/countertype-qualifier) (1073939712) , DefaultScale (0) , [PerfDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmisdk/perfdetail-qualifier) (100)
>
> Base value for `PercentDiskTime`.

Note that:

- *DefaultScale* (`sint32`) = Power of 10 to use for display of the counter. For zero, the estimated maximum is `10^0`, or `1`, and
- *PerfDetail* (`sint32`) = Audience level of knowledge. Not used. The value is always `100`.

### From [`Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa394262(v%3Dvs.85)):

> **PercentDiskTime**: Data type: `uint64`, Access type: Read-only
>
> *Qualifiers*: CookingType ("[PERF_PRECISION_100NS_TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms804015(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)") , Counter ("PercentDiskTime") , PerfTimeStamp ("TimeStamp_Sys100NS") ,
>   PerfTimeFreq ("Frequency_Sys100NS") , Base ("PercentDiskTime_Base")
>
> Percentage of elapsed time that the selected disk drive is busy
>   servicing read or write requests.

Take a look into [Property Qualifiers for Performance Counter Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmisdk/property-qualifiers-for-performance-counter-classes?redirectedfrom=MSDN#property-qualifiers-for-raw-and-formatted-performance-classes) as well.

A simple usage **example**:

```
$xxx = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk
$x0 = $xxx | Where-Object Name -eq '_Total' |
    Select-Object -Property Name, PercentDiskTime* 
$x0
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$xxx = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk
$xN = $xxx | Where-Object Name -eq '_Total' |
    Select-Object -Property Name, PercentDiskTime*
'----'
$xn
'----'
$FormattedPercentDiskTime = ( $xn.PercentDiskTime      - $x0.PercentDiskTime      ) / 
                            ( $xn.PercentDiskTime_Base - $x0.PercentDiskTime_Base )
100*$FormattedPercentDiskTime             # not sure about the `100*` multiplier
```

**Output**: `D:\PShell\SO\58712142.ps1`

> ```
> Name   PercentDiskTime PercentDiskTime_Base
> ----   --------------- --------------------
> _Total      2863146220   132202140117518636
> ----
> _Total      2863151515   132202140128078551
> ----
> 0,0501424490632737
> ```